# How to show only shared files to new flutter screen?

Tags: flutter

I have screen 1,  where I can upload, share  and delete documents.

Now I want screen 2, to show only the documents that I have shared from the screen 1.

How can I do that ?

Comment: What is the "shared from the screen 1". You didnt mention aboout sharing anything. Also can you show some code about your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Before sharing a document store the document in a `sharedDocList` list and pass this list as an argument in screen 2 `Screen2(docList: sharedDocList)`

```
class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {
    final List docList;
    Screen2({this.docList});
    ...
}
```